# Using the X -  Definition To Solve Limits

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital, epsilon-delta

Using the X -  definition, how must you prove that:
$$\lim_{x\to2} \frac{x}{(x-2)^2}=+∞$$

Can anyone please outline the method you used to solve this problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to make this easier is if you commit to making $\delta \le 1$. If that is the case, then
$$0 < |x - 2| < \delta \implies |x - 2| < 1 \implies x > 1.$$
So, under this assumption,
$$\frac{x}{(x - 2)^2} > \frac{1}{(x - 2)^2}.$$
Is that enough to help you start?